# Delete all related records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table for a survey, and wants to delete all records that are related to one certain survery.

My tables:

```
_______________     _______________     ___________  ________________
|_tblSurvey___|     |_tblAnswers___|    |_tblAlt__|  |_tblQuestions_|
| surveyID    |     | answerAltID  |    | altID   |  | questID      |
| surveyName  |     | userID       |    | altText |  | questText    |
|_____________|     |______________|    |_questID_|  |_surveyID_____|
```

Let's say I wanna delete all records that are related to surveyID 1.

I tried:

```
DELETE 
 * 
FROM tblSurvey, tblQuestions, tblAlt, tblAnswers
WHERE tblSurvey.surveyID = 1 
AND tblsurvey.surveyID = tblQuestions.surveyID
AND tblQuestions.questID = tblAlt.questID
AND tblAlt.altID = tblAnswers.answerAltID
```

Comment: Is your table called 'tblQuestion' or 'tblQuestions'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two ways:

- Set up foreign key constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
- Use a multiple-table `DELETE` statement.

Try this:

```
DELETE tblSurvey, tblQuestion, tblAlt, tblAnswers 
FROM tblSurvey
JOIN tblQuestion ON tblsurvey.surveyID = tblQuestion.surveyID
JOIN tblAlt ON tblQuestions.questID = tblAlt.questID
JOIN tblAnswers ON tblAlt.altID = tblAnswers.answerAltID 
WHERE tblSurvey.surveyID = 1
```

Comment: This query doesn't work, i think that it should say: DELETE * FROM … isn't it? or i'm wrong?

Comment: Thanks, Does not work using JOIN in MySQL version 5.7, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If your tables have foreign key references you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE`